# Vulnerability in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, web-browser, internet-explorer

*An attacker could host a specially crafted website that is designed to exploit this vulnerability through Internet Explorer and then convince a user to view the website.*

**This** here being `remote code execution vulnerability`. Would somebody be kind enough to throw some light on this issue. I've never worked in the field of Information Security, so its a bit difficult for me to understand.

As Albert Einstein once said:*“If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.”* . Kindly explain it in that manner.

Comment: As you'll see from questions we have had on the site regarding other vulnerabilities/attacks/bugs, you need to structure your post as a single question and follow the [ask] page guidance.

Comment: Is that good enough or am I just going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the page you linked you can find the CVE ID of the vulnerability: **CVE-2014-1776**.  This is the most likely way different people will refer to the same vulnerability and nearly everyone talking about it will include this ID.

A search for that ID finds many people talking about it but the [explanation from Symantec seems most suited to a 6-year-old](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/emerging-threat-microsoft-internet-explorer-zero-day-cve-2014-1776-remote-code-execution-vulne).

[FireEye (who are credited with the discovery of the vulnerability) have a more detailed write up](http://www.fireeye.com/blog/uncategorized/2014/04/new-zero-day-exploit-targeting-internet-explorer-versions-9-through-11-identified-in-targeted-attacks.html).

It's probably worth clarifying the distinction that this isn't just a *bug* that has been discovered but rather it's an active exploit that has been in use by malicious actors for some time.  FireEye discovered the attackers and by analysing what the attackers were doing, figured out the vulnerability and reported it to Micrososft.  The vulnerability is the same no matter how it was discovered but the risk is much greater because there are already people exploiting it.